# i need help getting my bitcoin back from an address

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, address, blockchain.info

i sent my bitcoin to another address i generated from another site not knowing they have a policy that if the bitcoin is not up to 0.005 it wont be able to reflect. now my question is that would my bitcoin be return to my account

Answer (score 1):

A bitcoin address represents a public key.  When you generated the address, did you also get or write down the corresponding private key?

If you have this private key, you can import it into any bitcoin wallet and you'll be able to return the BTC to the old address.  In fact you'll be able to send the BTC anywhere you want to.